# Uploading an image file, resizing it then inserting it into a table

Tags: php, image-upload

I've looked at this [PHP file upload/resize](http://salman-w.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html) method, but I have two questions.

1. When the image file is uploaded to the directory, the file is the name of the image uploaded from the person's device. I'd prefer it to be some kind of ID / number so that, for example, if person A uploads an image from their device called `image1.jpg` and so too does another person, it won't overwrite the original.
   I know that imgur uses a 7-character string with numbers 0-9 and letters a-Z, so maybe it could generate something similar but also check if it already exists, and if it does, generate another. I'm not sure how to achieve this kind of thing.
2. I also want to insert the image that's been uploaded into a table.

How could I achieve these two things using the method I linked?

Comment: In wordpress wp_handle_upload() takes care of this issue

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
      $newname = time().'_'.$_FILES['image']['name'];/*Rename image - New unique name of image*/
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$newname);/*upload image*/
      /*Now use this $newname and use it for insert into database*/
    }  
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```